# How to optimize the below code, requirement is to read the configuration from the xml on the object initialization event

Tags: xml, linq

How to optimize the below code, requirement is to read the configuration from the xml on the object initialization event.

```
try
{
    var XMLInput = (XDocument.Load(cmdParameters["Profile"].ToString()).Descendants("Profile")
        .Select(profile => new Profile
        {
            Server = profile.Element("Server").Value,
            Publication = Convert.ToInt32(profile.Element("Publication").Value)
        })).Single();

    this.ServerName = XMLInput.Server;
    this.NumberOfPublications = XMLInput.Publication;                        
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Logger.Log(string.Format("Unable to load the Profile : {0}", cmdParameters["Profile"].ToString()));
}
```

How could I directly load the values into the current object (this), instead of creating temp object and load.

Comment: What's the type of the current object? Is it a "Profile"?

Comment: No, It is a type of Configuration. Just created the Profile class to load the data temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create temporary `Profile` object, and get required values directly from `XElement` as also explained in the other answer. Beside that, you can cast `XElement` to `int` -or some other types*- directly to get the element's value in `int` type :

```cs
var profile = XDocument.Load(cmdParameters["Profile"].ToString())
                       .Descendants("Profile")
                       .Single();

this.ServerName = (string)profile.Element("Server");
this.NumberOfPublications = (int)profile.Element("Publication");
```

<sup>*</sup> : List of possible explicit conversions for `XElement` : [XElement Explicit Conversion Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create a new Profile object. You can get the property values directly from the `XElement` object, like below:

```cs
var xElement = (XDocument.Load(cmdParameters["Profile"].ToString())
    .Descendants("Profile").Single();

this.ServerName = xElement.Element("Server").Value;
this.NumberOfPublications = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("Publication").Value);
```

Note that this code assumes that the xElement object will never be null. If that's not the case, you may want to replace `Single()` with `SingleOrDefault()`, and check if the object is null before assigning the values.